# Windows Mobile 6.x How to explicitly lock the app in one orientation?

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

I'm trying to get an app on the WinMo App Store.

As part of this, Microsoft App's Store has asked that I need to support landscape as well as portrait.

What they've said is OK is:

> 1. If dynamic switching is implicitly allowed, the
>      app will be tested just as if it
>      supports both portrait and landscape
>      even if only a portrait or landscape
>      resolution is checked.
> 2. You may explicitly lock the app in one orientation (which means
>      portrait mode if the app does not
>      handle landscape mode functions), provided the default OS orientation is preserved once the app exits.

I'd love to do answer 2 - but I can't find any way of doing it - and they won't provide me any other clues - they suggested I ask on the forums... so here I am on Stack Overflow - far better than on the forums :)

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple enough, the details of how to handle portrait to landscape orientation change are provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839354.aspx#screen_orientation_awareness_topic2). That articles recommend repositioning layouts, buttons etc. So, for the app to remain in portrait mode only, when it receives `WM_SIZE` notification, dont change the display at all.

One more thing, it is a better user experience if you can display a message asking user to go back to portrait mode to use the app. Otherwise its a bit disorienting, as most apps nowadays handle orientation change seemlessly.